# Cómo cambiar la url que me aparece por defecto en "Inspección de urls" en Google Search Console

Tags: google-analytics, error500, google-search-console

Mi web no indexa y da un error "5xx", pero no consigo saber más sobre ese error.

Como es abrumador ver todas las cosas que hay que hacer para intentar averiguar por qué una web no indexa, una vez he repasado una serie de cosas en Wordpress que hay que tener en cuenta para que indexe, y que todas esas cosas están ok, lo primero que se me ocurre para tratar de revertir la mala situación es decirle a Google Search Console que me haga una "Inspección de URLs".

El problema es que en la caja de texto para inspeccionar al url, me aparece la url de mi web pero con "http" en lugar de "https" que es como está mi web. Y no me deja cambiarlo de ninguna manera. De ninguna.

Doy fe de que mi web está en https porque le hice preguntas a los de mi hosting y me confirmaron que para ellos tambíen les aparece como "https", pero como digo el Search Console no me deja cambiarlo ni aunque le cambie de la opción "http" a "https" que aparece en ese mismo campo de texto.

¿Alguna idea?
¿Algo que deba revistar también en Google Analytics?

Siento si no puedo ser más concisa, pero en un problema así es bastante difícil serlo más aún.

Comment: ariba a la izq ( UI 2022 ) donde esta el search property, click y agregar nueva property, agregas el dominio con https y ya podes usarlo. el enlace con analytics lo haces con esa nueva "propiedad", si empezaste con http y pasaste a https vas a ir viendo trafico y metricas bajar en una de las property y subir en la otra

Comment: 2/ el error 500 puede ser una redireccion circular de http a https y luego a con www o sin www . con un [chequeador de redirecciones](https://www.google.com/search?q=check+redirections) podes llegar a ver que ondas, lo normal es que la property http sólo tenga un hit esporádico y todo el trafico vaya via 302 a su equivalente https